# How can the server only allow pre-approved clients to communicate with it

Tags: java, c++, c

I wonder how can the server makes sure that the requests that are coming from clients are coming from only valid pre-approved clients, can anyone let me know what algorithm to use and what are my options?

Comment: What's the definition of valid you're using? Are you specifically referring to web-based transactions?

Comment: you going to have to put in a bit of effort....

Comment: by valid means say in http based server we want only our developed clients to be connecting to and not others writing some custom clients, can I use some secrey key mechanism?

Comment: Hi Mitch, that is exactly I am wondering is where to start so that I can put that effort. I have googled a bit but having someone commenting on this would make my work easier and faster and that is why I am asking

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to keep other people from writing clients that work with your application. If they can watch the network traffic between your client and server and they have a copy of your application they can figure it out. You can try to make it difficult with encryption but you're just slowing them down, not stopping them.

Comment: Hi Sarel, could you let me know some ideas so that I can at least slow them down?

Comment: Code obfuscation to protect the distributed code and encryption to protect the network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to implement mutual authentication - where the server and the client are both assured of the authenticity of each other's identity.

This is a fairly new concept as it's usually one-sided authentication.  I'd start here, with a full-fledged example on the oracle site using web services.  You can't get much more reliable information than that :)

**Excerpt from the link:**

> When you send messages with mutual authentication, a connection is possible only if the client trusts the server's certificate and the server trusts the client's certificate. The process of exchanging certificates and setting up connection properties is called the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) handshake. For details, see the section, "SSL Protocol Overview," in the Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) Reference Guide.

http://developers.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/mutual_auth.html

Answer (score 0):

I send a secret code as the first message from the client a certain time period after it connects to the server. If this is not received, the client is disconnected.
Further to this, you can take note of the IP Address of the client and then prevent further connections from this client, maybe for a certain time duration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to handle the full X.509 certificate hassle, [TLS provides options to authenticate client certificates as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake).

With this, your clients can only authenticate if they have the correct client certificate installed.

It isn't appropriate for every situation (for example, most banks don't seem to care) but it might be perfect for *your* situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much impossible to keep other people from writing clients that work with your application. If they can watch the network traffic between your client and server and they have a copy of your application they can figure it out. You can try to make it difficult but you're just slowing them down, not stopping them.

You can use code obfuscation to protect the distributed code and encryption to protect the network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. When you say, Pre-approved, does it mean pre-registered? If yes, you will have their credentials (which could be username/password or IP address etc) to validate when they connect to the server.

If this HTTP server is intended to be used only by certain user group, you can host internally (intranet) or allow only approved IP addresses in firewall.